# Move ScrollView under the RecyclerView does not work

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I have the following xml, it works but I do not want to use scrollview as a parent. I want scrollview under the recyclerview. I do not want whole page to scroll, I only want a certain part of my screen to be scrollable. In my current xml, even toolbar is scrollable, I do not want it. But when I move scrollview under the recyclerview, I does not like it and getting the following issue.

I have remove some portion of my xml to easy for you to follow. Please do not consider that xml is missing some components. I only want GridLayout which is under the recyclerview to be scrollable.

> Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can
>   host only one direct child (Details)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        tools:context=".PostProductActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp" />

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:columnCount="2">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                 <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextPrice"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:inputType="text|number"
                    android:hint="@string/price"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </GridLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood properly, you want `ScrollView` under `RecyclerView` (so not `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView`).

Try this approach.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="1">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnSpan="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPrice"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:hint="@string/price"
                    android:inputType="text|number"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you have any idea in the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582151/image-scroll-transtion

Answer (score 1):

Try to put it below your `Toolbar` as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    />
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".PostProductActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:columnCount="2">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

             <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextPrice"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:inputType="text|number"
                android:hint="@string/price"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I not only want toolbar, also I want recyclerview not to be scrollable vertically. recyclerview has its own scroller inherently.

Comment: What do you want to scroll then?

Comment: I only want gridLayout to be scrollable.

Comment: Then you can do it creating a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout one per your RecyclerView and another for your GridView, then put the ScrollView before the Linear/Relative of your Grid and let me know if it works.