# Image Page Scroll Transtion

Tags: android

I have the following xml. I am getting a json object from the server and parse them and display the images on the screen. The following xml and implementation works, but there is an issue with my implementation.

I am listening touch event on the image. If touch event direction is left then show previous image, if it is right show next image. Since this touch event within the scrollview, performance wise it is not satisfactory. It is not so smooth, it is confusing sometimes between touch event and scroll view.

It seems to me that I am doing rocket science here; therefore, I started thinking there should be simpler way of doing it.

```
<ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/my_scrollview"
  android:layout_below="@id/imageLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scrollbars="horizontal"
  android:fillViewport="true">

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="300dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/blue"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:id="@+id/detailImage"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

       <RadioGroup
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:id="@+id/radiogroup">
        </RadioGroup>

   </FrameLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

**Implementation:**

```
 obj = new JSONObject(jsonObject);
 JSONObject images_JsonObject =  obj.getJSONObject("images");
 numberOfItems =  images_JsonObject.length();
 createRadioButton(numberOfItems);

 // parse json object
 Iterator<String> stringIterable =  images_JsonObject.keys();
 HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
 list = new ArrayList<>();

 while (stringIterable.hasNext()){
    String key = stringIterable.next();
    hashMap.put(key, images_JsonObject.getString(key));
    list.add(images_JsonObject.getString(key));
 }

 //initial loading
 loadProductImage(list.get(0));
 radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(0).getId());
 // touch event listener
 productImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

   private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    View v;

     @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        this.v = v;
        switch (event.getAction()) { // Check vertical and horizontal touches
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
             downX = event.getX();
             downY = event.getY();
             return true;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
             upX = event.getX();
             upY = event.getY();
             float deltaX = downX - upX;
             float deltaY = downY - upY;

        //HORIZONTAL SCROLL
          if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
                if (deltaX < 0) {
                   this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                   return true;
                }
                if (deltaX > 0) {
                    this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                    return true;
                }
           }
         return false;
        }
      }
    return false;
   }

    public void onLeftToRightSwipe() {
     selectedItem = mod(selectedItem - 1, 5);
     radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(selectedItem).getId());
     loadProductImage(list.get(selectedItem));
   }

    public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
      selectedItem = mod(selectedItem + 1, 5);
       radioGroup.check(radioGroup.getChildAt(selectedItem).getId());
       loadProductImage(list.get(selectedItem));
    }
  });


// Add radio button programmatically
 private void createRadioButton(int nImages) {
    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[nImages];
    radioGroup.removeAllViews();
    for(int i=0; i<nImages; i++){
        rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
        radioGroup.addView(rb[i]);
        rb[i].setId(i);
    }
  }
```

Here is the UI Snapshot from my app. It is not neccessary to add radio buttons, all I want to give impression to a user that there are more images if he scrolls.

[image]

However, the following snapshot is from other app, that looks like more standard and works more smoothly and there is no lag and transition between images are so smooth.

[image]

Comment: If you want to implement a kind of image gallery, it's probably better to use a ViewPager and put an image on each page.

Comment: Does ViewPager has page indicator?

Comment: It doesn't include indicator by default but it's possible to add it quite easily. I can provide you some sample code but I need some time for preparing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ViewPager` for horizontally scrolling images.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html#viewpager) it is a reference from Android documentation.

[Here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/stackoverflow/tree/so-35582151) on GitHub I put a sample project implementing this solution, using a custom pager indicator and [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library for loading images.